# Release-build for HTML 5 app in Sublime Text 2

Tags: html, cordova, sublimetext2, build-system

I have an HTML 5 PhoneGap app that I'm developing using Sublime Text 2.

I have config.debug.js and config.release.js files which do exactly what they say: The debug file is for local testing and the release file is for the zip that gets built with PhoneGap.

What is the best method for discerning which script to load?

My first thought is to create a custom build system in sublime text 2 that will rename the release script to the debug script and then package it using 7zip. This didn't work because Sublime Text build systems expect programs and arguments, not a series of terminal commands.

Comment: why not put together a shell script/batch file with appropriate command-line options and use that as your build system?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that but I get the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect" on all of my renames such as "rename js/config.release.js config.js". Any ideas?